# API to know box office movie collection

Tags: api, movie

Hi folks i am searching for **api** which will give me box office collection of movie.In my project i am trying to display information of movie so it would be nice if i can show box office collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Wikipedia page of movie display gross collection info in **infobox**.To fetch the  Infobox from wiki page api named **Mediawiki** can be used and from Infobox using **regular expression** you can extract gross collection of movie.

To extract the infobox box **python** code is available at below link

> https://github.com/siznax/wptools/find/master

Once you get infobox you can use following method to get box collection

**answer contains o/p from wp_info.py**

```
def getAnswer(answer):                    
    gross_list=re.findall(r'^| gross.*',answer,re.I)
    print gross_list
    if len(gross_list) > 1:
        gross=""
        for item in gross_list:
            if re.search(r'INRConvert',str(item),re.I) != None:
                gross=re.findall(r'\|\d*.\d+\|\w',str(item),re.I)
        if len(gross) !=0:
            ans=gross[0].replace('|','').replace('b',' billion').replace('c',' cr').replace('m',' million')
            print "Gross = ",ans

        else:
            print "No info in DB"

    else:
        print "No info in DB"
```

Comment: Thanx buddy.This programe works with Bollywood movies when i enter any Hollywood movies i get no o/p.can you help

Comment: re.findall(r'\$\d*.\d+ \w+',str(item),re.I)     check re for gross currency in $